# Connecting Javascript file in flask

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have been following along a tutorial on flask, and came to the very end - trying to delete notes. I click on the x and nothing appears to happen. Finally, I opened the console and it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteNote is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick".

I eventually looked at what the page is reading, and found the problem, but do not know how to correct it. I have a base.html and a home.html. Reads most of the base.html, then skips to home.html (where my Javascript implementation is) and then finishes the base.html where I actually link my Javascript file.

Here is my base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <title>{% block title%}Home{% endblock %}</title>

</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"> </span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <!--this is the actual navigation items)-->
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="home" href="/">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="logout" href="/logout">Logout</a> {% else %}
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="login" href="/login">Login</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="signUp" href="/sign-up">Sign Up</a> {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %} {% if messages %} {% for category, message in messages %} {% if category == 'error' %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade show" role="alert">
        {{message}}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade show" role="alert">
        {{message}}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
    </div>
    {% endif %} {% endfor %} {% endif %} {% endwith %}

    <div class="container">
        {% block content %} {% endblock %}
    </div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

here is my home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Home{% endblock %} {% block content %}
<h1 align="center">Notes</h1>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="notes">
    {% for note in user.notes %}
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ note.data }}
        <button type="button" class="close" onClick="deleteNote({{ note.id }})">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>

<form method="POST">
    <textarea name="note" id="note" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <br>
    <div align="center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Note</button>
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

and here is what the web page reads

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <title>Home</title>

</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"> </span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <!--this is the actual navigation items)-->
                
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="home" href="/">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="logout" href="/logout">Logout</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

      

    <div class="container">
        
<h1 align="center">Notes</h1>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="notes">
    
    <li class="list-group-item">hello
        <button type="button" class="close" onClick="deleteNote(1)">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    
    <li class="list-group-item">hello
        <button type="button" class="close" onClick="deleteNote(2)">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    
    <li class="list-group-item">hi

        <button type="button" class="close" onClick="deleteNote(3)">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    
    <li class="list-group-item">hello
        <button type="button" class="close" onClick="deleteNote(4)">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    
    <li class="list-group-item">hello
        <button type="button" class="close" onClick="deleteNote(5)">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    
    <li class="list-group-item">hello
        <button type="button" class="close" onClick="deleteNote(6)">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    
    <li class="list-group-item">hello
        <button type="button" class="close" onClick="deleteNote(7)">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    
    <li class="list-group-item">hello
        <button type="button" class="close" onClick="deleteNote(8)">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    

</ul>

<form method="POST">
    <textarea name="note" id="note" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <br>
    <div align="center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Note</button>
    </div>
</form>


    </div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

here is my javascript file

```
function deleteNote(noteId) {
    fetch("/delete-note", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({ noteId: noteId }),
    }).then((_res) => {
        window.location.href = "/";
    });
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Error seems self-explanatory--where did you define `deleteNote`?

Comment: perhaps you could share your JS file. the one at `/static/index.js`

Comment: I edited it to have the javascript file. sorry, I forgot about that.

Comment: can't reproduce. if you open your page and click `/static/index.js`, does it open your JS file?

Comment: AudioBaton - Yes it does.

Comment: Okay, so after everything had been closed out for a while, I restarted VS Code, ran the server and now everything works fine. Must have been a glitch/bug? Thank you.